# Scraping HTML in lisp

Tags: html, html-parsing, common-lisp

My question is related to another question found here [Scraping an HTML table in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352561/scraping-an-html-table-in-common-lisp)

I am trying to extract data from a webpage in common lisp. I am currently using drakma to send the http request, and I'm trying to use chtml to extract the data I am looking for. The webpage I'm trying to scrap is http://erg.delph-in.net/logon, here is my code

```
(defun send-request (sentence)
 "sends sentence in an http request to logon for parsing, and recieves
  back the webpage containing the MRS output"
 (drakma:http-request "http://erg.delph-in.net/logon" 
                   :method :post 
                   :parameters `(("input" . ,sentence)
                                 ("task" . "Analyze")
                                 ("roots" . "sentences")
                                 ("output" . "mrs")
                                 ("exhaustivep" . "best")
                                 ("nresults" . "1"))))
```

And here's the function I am having trouble with

```
(defun get-mrs (sentence)
    (let* (
       (str (send-request sentence))
       (document (chtml:parse str (cxml-stp:make-builder))))
      (stp:filter-recursively (stp:of-name "mrsFeatureTop") document)))
```

Basically all the data I need to extract is in an html table, it's too big to paste here though. In my get-mrs function, i was just trying to get the tag with name mrsFeatureTop, I am not sure if this is correct though since I am getting an error: not an NCName 'onclick. Any help with scraping the table will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks wvxvw, I agree that a lot of webpages are rubbish. I will try out your suggestion. You've helped me a lot before with other questions btw, I thank you for that :).

Answer (score 3):

Ancient question, I know.  But one that that defeated me for a long time.  It's true that a lot of webpages are rubish, but nearly the entire 2.0 is build upon screen scraping, integrating heterogeneous websites with hack upon hack -- should be an ideal application for Lisp!

The key (in addition to drakma) is [lquery](https://shinmera.github.io/lquery/) which allows you to access the pages contents using a lispy transliteration of css selectors (what jquery uses).

Let's get the links from the media strip on Google's news page!  If you open https://news.google.com in a browser and view source.  You'll be overwhelmed by the complexity of the page.  But if you view the page in the browsers development panel (Firefox: F12, Inspector) You'll see the page has some logic to it.  Use the search box to find .media-strip-table  That element contains the images we want.  Now open your favourite repl. (Well, let's be honest here, Emacs: `M-x slime`)

```lisp
(ql:quickload '(:drakma :lquery))

;;; Get the links from the media strip on Google's news page.
(defparameter response  (drakma:http-request "https://news.google.com/"))

;;; lquery parses the page and gets it ready to be queried.
(lquery:$ (initialize http-response))
```

Now let's explore the results

```lisp
;;; package qualified '$' opperator, Barbaric!  
;;; Use (use-package :lquery) to omit the package prefix.
(lquery:$ ".media-strip-table" (html))
```

Wow!  that's just a tiny section of the page?  Ok, how about the first element?

```lisp
(elt (lquery:$ ".media-strip-table" (html)) 0)
```

OK, that's a little more manageable.  Let's see if there's an image tag in there somewhere, Emacs: `C-s img`  Yay! There it is.

```lisp
(lquery:$ ".media-strip-table img" (html))
```

Hmmm... It's finding something, but only returning empty text... Oh yeah, image tags are supposed to be empty!

```lisp
(lquery:$ ".media-strip-table img" (attr :src))
```

Holy crap!  gif's aren't just used for unfunny, grainy animations?

Comment: +1 for lquery ! which lives here: https://shinmera.github.io/lquery/ (and also a little tutorial for web scraping: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/web-scraping.html